# Rewritting a for loop as an apply, which doesn't have a set of predefined values to loop over besides a number of loops

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I'm making a small script, which given an initial value, will calculate some further values and store them. My function is currently this:

```
func1 <- function(n, p, val){
  vals <- c(val)
  for(i in (1:n)){
    newVal <- getNewVal(p, val = tail(vals,n=1))
    vals <- c(vals, newVal)
  }
  return(vals)
}
```

Given that I don't actually have a set value list, and that I will keep going `n` times from the last generated value, I can't think how this can be turned into an apply(), storing getting the new value, storing it to the vals list and then calling it again with the last element in vals.

Is this possible?

Example input:

```
func1(10, 0.5, 1)
output vals (1,4,5,3,7,2,4,9,8,6,2)
```

**Edit:** getNewVal(), given a number p and a val, will calculate a new val.

Comment: "Given that I don't actually have a set value list", what do you mean by "a set value list" ?

Comment: Maybe also add example input and expected output?

Comment: I see what your problem is and in my opinion there is unfortunately no other solution than a for loop.

Comment: A for loop is the only operation I know that actualizes the values between each incrementation

Comment: @zx8754 I mean that usually you have a list/vector/matrix/df of values to which you apply a function to transform them somehow or to produce a new result from those values. For example `a <- c(1,2,3), apply(a, 1, func(a*2))`. I need to get a list of new values starting from a single value.

Comment: @T.Ciffréo I think so too. I've read many answers on here but haven't been able to find something similar to my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There several ways to go about this (it would help if you provided `getNewVal`)

## 1. Using reduce

Your task boils down to `x_n+1 = f(x_n); x_0 = const.` This is the typical use-case for `reduce`:

```
# Reduce
  func_Reduce <- function (n, p, val) Reduce(function (x,y) getNewVal(p = p, val = x), 
                                             x = 1:n, init = val, accumulate = TRUE)
```

---

## 2. Using the apply family

Here is a solution using `vapply` from the apply family

```
# Apply
  func_vapply <- function (n, p, val) vapply(0:n,
    function(i, p, val){
      if (i == 0) {
        vals <<- val # overwrites in the func. env.
        return (val)
      }
      newVal <- getNewVal(p, val = vals[length(vals)])
      vals <<- c(vals, newVal) # overwrites in the func. env.
      return(newVal)
    }, numeric(1), p = p, val = val)
```

The thing here is one needs to use `<<-` in order to keep track of the last element of `vals`.

---

## 3. Using a recursion

This task can also be done with a recursion

```
# Recursion  
func_recursive <- function(n, p, val){
  if (n == 0) return (val)
  vals <- func_recursive (n-1, p, val)
  newVal <- getNewVal(p, val = vals[length(vals)])
  c(vals, newVal)
}
```

Although recursions should be used with a certain caution.

---

## Examples

Here is an example:

```
# Dummy function
getNewVal <- function (p, val) val %/% p  
# Arguments
n <- 17
p <- 3
val <- 45459748

# Examples
func_Reduce(n = n, p = p, val = val)
func_vapply(n = n, p = p, val = val)
func_recursive(n = n, p = p, val = val)
# all yielding
# [1] 45459748 15153249  5051083  1683694   561231   187077    62359    20786     6928     2309      769      256       85       28        9        3        1        0

# benchmarking
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(func_Reduce(n = n, p = p, val = val),
                               func_vapply(n = n, p = p, val = val),
                               func_recursive(n = n, p = p, val = val)
                               )  
# Unit: microseconds
#                                    expr    min     lq     mean median      uq    max neval cld
#    func_Reduce(n = n, p = p, val = val) 25.163 26.257 28.65292 26.986 27.3515 82.417   100  a 
#    func_vapply(n = n, p = p, val = val) 30.268 30.998 32.82484 31.363 32.4570 80.958   100   b
# func_recursive(n = n, p = p, val = val) 23.339 24.798 27.16511 25.527 26.2570 82.417   100  a
```